# While Loops - Getting user inputs to multiply together

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to get this loop to repeat so the integers the user enters will multiply together. What my program is doing now is multiplying just the *last* integer entered together, and will disregard any previous entered inputs.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ch5HwNo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String more = "y"; 
        int product = 0;

        while (more.equals("y"))
        {
            String num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter integers: ");
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num1);                   

            more = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("More integers? (y/n): ");     
            product = (num2 * num2);
        }                   
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, product , "Integer Product", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
product = num2 * num2;
```

you are not using any previous value. You have to do this:

```
product = product * num2;
```

but, since here you are multiplying `product` with the number entered, you will need to initialize product with `1`:

```
int product = 1;
```

If you initialized `product` with `0`, the operation `product * num2` would ever return `0`.